# The type or namespace name 'ForeignKey' could not be found

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and entity framework version 6.0.0.0 (code first), I've created a class as:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace IRANMVCCore.Domain.Entity
{
   public class UserProperty
    {
        [key]
        [ForeignKey("Instructor")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "error")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "error")]
        public string Famil { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "error")]
        public string City { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "error")]
        public string Countries { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now I am getting this error:

> Error CS0246  The type or namespace name 'ForeignKey' could not be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have reference :
[Refrances](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGIWr.png)

How can I solved it?

Comment: Shouldn't `[key]` be `[Key]`?

Comment: tanks [key] be [Key] is worked but i still have error" Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'ForeignKey' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) To solve it check your reference version of:

`System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`

2) `[key]` should be `[Key]`

Hope this helps anyone else

Comment: not worked !!  look at top of  my code i had "using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;"

Comment: @NorouziFar Try this: Others might hit this: Do the following if you're forced to downgrade after upgrading. (a) Uninstall EF from Nuget (b) Set the target .NET framework (c) reinstall EF (d) ensure that the .Schema reference is added.

Comment: i find my problem : i used System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations version 5 but i should using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations version 4

Comment: please edit your answer  i selected it accept answer

Answer (score 2):

Add a reference to `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema` as well.